# Getting Exception Type: KeyError Exception Value: 'pk' in class CreateCheckoutSessionView(APIView)'s post method in line: hotel_id=self.kwargs["pk"]

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, stripe-payments

I've integrated stripe payment gateway in my webapp(backend: django, frontend: reactjs). I'm fetching the details of hotels from DRF using axios in frontend to display all the hotels cards. On clicking a particular hotel card it's information page opens where that particular hotel's information is displayed and that particular hotel's id is fetched using useParams. So on clicking a particular hotel card it's information is displayed and now I have a payment button which on click should open the stripe payment gateway and that payment information should display that hotel's price,image only.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
# Create your models here.

class Hotels(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300,default=" ")
    email = models.EmailField()

    #address
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=" ")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=" ")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=" ")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=" ")
    pincode = models.IntegerField(default=00)

    #contacts
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=4,default=" ")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=" ")
    # phone=models.BigIntegerField(max_length=10)

    #accessiblity
    visual_impaired=models.BooleanField(default=0)
    wheelchair_user=models.BooleanField(default=0)
    hearing_impaired=models.BooleanField(default=0)
    speech_impaired=models.BooleanField(default=0)
    
    #extra
    facility = models.TextField(default=" ")
    # rooms = models.IntegerField()
    # price = models.IntegerField()
    # ac_rooms = models.BooleanField()
    roomtype1=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Regular")
    roomtype2=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Regular")
    roomtype3=models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Regular")
    pricetype1=models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    pricetype2=models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    pricetype3=models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    facilityoftype1=models.TextField(default=" ")
    facilityoftype2=models.TextField(default=" ")
    facilityoftype3=models.TextField(default=" ")


    image=models.CharField(max_length=500,default=" ")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

# Create your views here.

from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from exploreHotels.models import Hotels
from exploreHotels.serializer import ExploreHotelSerializer
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from django.views import View
import stripe
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import permissions
# Create your views here.

stripe.api_key=settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

class HotelList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=Hotels.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ExploreHotelSerializer
    filter_backends=[DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter]
    search_fields=['name','landmark','city','state','country','pincode']
    filterset_fields=['city','wheelchair_user','hearing_impaired','visual_impaired','speech_impaired']

class SingleHotel(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset=Hotels.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ExploreHotelSerializer
    permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny]


class CreateCheckoutSessionView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        hotel_id=self.kwargs["pk"]
        #hotel_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        try:
            hotel=Hotels.objects.get(id=hotel_id)
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price_data':{
                            'currency':'Inr',
                            'unit_amount':int(hotel.pricetype1)*100,
                            'product_data':{
                                'name':hotel.name,
                                'images':[hotel.image],
                            },
                        },
                    'quantity': 1,
                },
            ],
            metadata={
                    "product_id":hotel.id
                },
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='payment',
            # success_url=settings.SITE_URL + '/?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            success_url=settings.SITE_URL + '/?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=settings.SITE_URL + '/?canceled=true',
        )
            return redirect(checkout_session.url)
        except:
            return Response(
                {'error':'Something went wrong when creating strip checkout session'},
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from exploreHotels import views;


urlpatterns = [
    path('hotels/',views.HotelList.as_view(),name="genericview"),
    path('hotel/<int:pk>',views.SingleHotel.as_view(),name="hotel"),
    path('create-checkout-session',views.CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='checkout_session')
]
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Contactus from './Components/Contactus/Contactus';
import ViewPlaces from './Components/pages/ViewPlaces';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ViewHotels from './Components/pages/ViewHotels';
import Home from './Components/pages/Home';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar'
import About from './Components/pages/About';
import SignUp from './Components/pages/SignUp';
import PlaceDetails from './Components/pages/PlaceDetails';
import HotelDetails from './Components/pages/HotelDetails';

function App(){

    return(
      <div>
         <BrowserRouter>

         <Navbar/>
         {/* <ReactPlayer url={'./travelvideo.mp4'} controls={false} playing={true} /> */}

        <div>
        <Routes>  
          <Route exact path='/' element={< Home />}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/about' element={< About />}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/places' element={< ViewPlaces />}></Route>  
          <Route exact path='/hotels' element={< ViewHotels />}></Route> 
          <Route exact path='/signup' element={< SignUp />}></Route> 
          <Route exact path='/places/:pid' element={<PlaceDetails/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/hotels/:hid' element={<HotelDetails/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <footer>
        <Contactus/> 
        </footer>

        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>

      </div>
    )

}

export default App;
```

**HotelDetails.js**

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import DetailedCard from './DetailedCard';
import { API_URL } from '../../config/index';

function HotelDetails() {

    const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    let params = useParams();
    console.log("Params : ", params)
    let hid = params.hid;
    console.log(hid)
    let info={};

    useEffect(() =>{
      const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  
      if (query.get("success")) {
        console.log("Order placed! You will receive an email confirmation.");
      }
  
      if (query.get("canceled")) {
        console.log(
          "Order canceled -- continue to shop around and checkout when you're ready."
        );
      }

        let data;
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stripe/hotels/')
        .then(res => {
            data=res.data;
            setDetails({
                details: data
            });
            setLoading(false);
        }) 
        .catch(err => { })
    },[]);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
          <div>
          <h2>loading....</h2>
        </div>
        )
      } else {
    return ( 
      <div>
 { Object.entries(details.details).map(([key, value]) => {
    if(key==hid-1){
          {info=value}
    }
 })}
  <DetailedCard image={info.image} name={info.name} description={info.facility} location={info.landmark}  vi={info.visual_impaired} wu={info.wheelchair_user} hi={info.hearing_impaired} si={info.speech_impaired}/>
    <div className="product">
      <img
        src={info.image}
        alt={info.name}
      />
      <div className="description">
      <h3>{info.name}</h3>
      <h5>{info.pricetype1}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action={`${API_URL}/api/stripe/create-checkout-session`} method="POST">
      <button type="submit">
        Checkout
      </button>
      
      
    </form>
    

      </div>
      
    )
  }
}

export default HotelDetails
```

How do I get the hotel's id from frontend to views.py in backend so that I can pass that hotel's details in the stripe's python code.

in views.py, if inside try block i write
`hotel=Hotels.objects.get(id=2)` 
,instead of
`hotel=Hotels.objects.get(id=hotel_id)`
then stripe payment gateway opens without error but displays the information of hotel with id=2 for any hotel.

Comment: 1. change the name of model from `Hotels` to `Hotel`. Name of the model shouldn't be in plural. And instead of `default=" "` you can use `null=True, blank=True`.